# Short "Star Wars" comic where Luke and Leia encounter an alien in deep space, who defeats a Star Destoyer with antimatter blobs

Tags: star-wars, comics, episode-identification

I remember this from some thin comic from the 80s, possibly before *The Empire Strikes Back* came out.

The artstyle was European-ish (Adamov? Moebius?) and the subject was Luke and Leia (both inexplicably in still in their *A New Hope* outfits; do princesses ever change out of their ambassadorial gowns? do sand peasants change their keikogi?) on a Tantive-IV style ship encounter a wandering alien's vessel in deep space (actually this should not be that surprising in the *Star Wars* universe).

They are taken aboard. A pursuing Star Destroyer looking for aggro and considering everything not Imperial as something that needs to be destroyed engages in pointless hostilities and is removed immediately by the alien using antimatter blobs. Luke and Leia are sent back to their ship, and the alien departs, *Galactica*-style. The End!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*Star Wars 38: Riders in the Void*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_38:_Riders_in_the_Void), published in 1980.

The cover of the comic shows Luke in his "Farmboy" outfit and Leia in her "Ambassador" gown and hair-buns. They look remarkably unlike either Hamill or Fisher on the cover, but that's how comics go sometimes.

There's a space-based alien/organic vessel called "Ship" who uses antimatter as its primary weapon and obliterates both an Imperial Star Destroyer and several TIE fighters. "Ship" takes Luke and Leia's ship inside itself and later departs into the unknown at the end of the comic after destroying the ISD and TIEs.

[image: Luke and Leia witnessing the effects of anti-matter pods]

They don't, however, use a CR90 Corvette (the *Tantive IV*-style ship), but that seems to be the only discrepancy between your description and the comic itself.

Comment: No question about it - that's the one!

Comment: While the style is unusual it is neither Moebius or Adamov. But it _is_ unusual. Thank you for the response, would upvote twice.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Glad to be of help. Do wish people would ask before editing my answers, though...

Comment: "Do wish people would ask before editing my answers, though..." Because someone posted content? Well, this _is_ StackOverflow.

Comment: Nah, 'cause someone went and changed some wording. The pic is fine, lol. (I'm not really complaining, I'm fine with it if it's a helpful edit, but a little "Hi I did X to your answer, if that's fine." would be nice.)